# ftptask on nant 0.85

Tags: .net, ftp, nant, ccnet-config, build-script

how do u upload files to a fpt server in nant?
i used the following code but it says that attribute server is unknown.

```
<ftp server="ftp.server.name.com"
            userid="user"
            password="user123"
            remotedir="/the_dir_in_remote_file">
            <fileset dir="dir_to_be_moved"/>
        </ftp>
```

i use the ftptask library i cant figure out what is wrong..please help
thanx

Comment: Please post a code sample that's causing you problems.

Comment: [This stackoverflow question][1] also discusses FTP and NAnt. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791613/upload-file-with-ftp-using-nant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [the library documentation](http://www.spinthemoose.com/~ftptask/help/tasks/ftp.html) helpful. The server, username (not userid), password and remotedir belong to a separate connection tag which you should reference in the ftp tag:

```
<connection id="ftpserver" 
            server="ftp.server.name.com" 
            username="user" 
            password="user123" />
<ftp connection="ftpserver" >
  <put remotedir="the_dir_in_remote_file">
    <include name="dir_to_be_moved\**" />
  </put>
</ftp>
```

The above snippet works with the latest version of NAnt and FTPTask

Comment: The link to the library documentation gives a 404.

Comment: @NikolaosGeorgiou It looks like the project has been moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/davidalpert/NAntFTPTask). The only place I could find the docs currently is in the [task source code](https://github.com/davidalpert/NAntFTPTask/blob/master/Tasks/ftptask.cs).

Answer (score 1):

You may use the WinSCP (free ftp client for windows) and integrate it through nant  tag. I blogged about it [here](http://www.whatthecodesays.co.uk/Blog/2012/1/NAnt-FTP-using-WinSCP)